# C++ C2440 Error, cannot convert from 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'LPCTSTR'

Tags: c++

Unfortunately I have been tasked with compiling an old C++ DLL so that it will work on Win 7 64 Bit machines.  I have zero C++ experience.  I have muddled through other issues, but this one has stumped me and i have not found a solution elsewhere.  The following code is throwing a C2440 compiler error.

The error: "error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'LPCTSTR'"

the code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Antenna.h"
#include "MyTypes.h"
#include "objbase.h"

const TCHAR* CAntenna::GetMdbPath()
{
    if(m_MdbPath.size() <= 0) return NULL;
    return LPCTSTR(m_MdbPath.begin());
}
```

"m_MdbPath" is defined in the Antenna.h file as
     string m_MdbPath;

Any assistance or guidance someone could provide would be extremely helpful.  Thank you in advance.  I am happy to provide additional details on the code if needed.

Comment: `return m_MdbPath.c_str();`

Comment: That worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @DieterLücking: FFS.

Comment: @samm -- Please note -- A `std::string` is not compatible with a `TCHAR` if you compiled this as `UNICODE`.  You will get a compiler error even if you returned `c_str()`, since the types are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

std::string has a .c_str() member function that should accomplish what you're looking for. It will return a const char* (const wchar_t* with std::wstring). std::string also has an empty() member function and I recommend using nullptr instead of the NULL macro.

```
const TCHAR* CAntenna::GetMdbPath()
{
    if(m_MdbPath.empty()) return nullptr;
    return m_MdbPath.c_str();
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work if compiled as Unicode.  The return type of `std::string::c_str( )` is not the same as a `TCHAR*`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the return type of `std::wstring::c_str()` will be. The other option is `_bstr_t()` if you're compiling with Unicode. Is there a better solution?

Comment: The better solution is to either typedef your `std::(w)string` type to fit the build type, or just plain old use UNICODE and `std::wstring`, since MBCS builds are rare these days.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
const TCHAR* CAntenna::GetMdbPath()
{
    if(m_MdbPath.size() <= 0) return NULL;
    return m_MdbPath.c_str();
}
```

will work if you can guarantee that your program is using the `MBCS` character set option (or if the Character Set option is set to `Not Set`if you're using Visual Studio), since a `std::string` character type will be the same as the `TCHAR` type.

However, if your build is `UNICODE`, then a `std::string` character type will not be the same as the `TCHAR` type, since `TCHAR` is defined as a wide character, not a single-byte character.  Thus returning `c_str()` will give a compiler error.  So your original code, plus the tentative fix of returning `std::string::c_str()` may work, but it is technically wrong with respect to the types being used.

You should be working directly with the types presented to your function -- if the type is `TCHAR`, then you should be using `TCHAR` based types, but again, a `TCHAR` is a type that changes definition depending on the build type.

As a matter of fact, the code will fail miserably at runtime if it were a `UNICODE` build and to fix the compiler error(s), you casted to an `LPCTSTR` to keep the compiler quiet.  You cannot cast a string pointer type to another string pointer type.  Casting is not converting, and merely casting will not convert a narrow string into a wide string and vice-versa.  You will wind up with at the least, odd characters being used or displayed, and worse, a program with random weird behavior and crashes.

In addition to this you never know when you really will need to build a UNICODE version of the DLL, since MBCS builds are becoming more rare.  Going by your original post, the DLL's usage of `TCHAR` indicates that yes, this DLL may (or even has) been built for UNICODE.

---

There are a few alternate solutions that you can use.  Note that some of these solutions may require you to make additional coding changes beyond the string types.  If you're using C++ stream objects, they may also need to be changed to match the character type (for example, `std::ostream` and `std::wostream`)

---

**Solution 1. Use a `typedef`, where the string type to use depends on the build type.**

For example:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
   typedef std::wstring tchar_string;
#else
   typedef std::string tchar_string;
#endif
```

and then use `tchar_string` instead of `std::string`.  Switching between MBCS and UNICODE builds will work without having to cast strin types, but requires coding changes.

---

**Solution 2. Use a `typedef` to use `TCHAR` as the underlying character type in the `std::basic_string` template.**

For example:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tchar_string;
```

And use `tchar_string` in your application.  You get the same public interface as `std::(w)string` and this allows you to switch between MBCS and UNICODE build seamlessly (with respect to the string types).

---

**Solution 3.  Go with UNICODE builds and drop MBCS builds altogether**

If the application you're building is a new one, then `UNICODE` is the default option (at least in Visual Studio) when creating a new application.  Then all you really need to do is use `std::wstring`.

This is sort of the opposite of the original solution given of making sure you use `MBCS`, but IMO this solution makes more sense if there is only going to be one build type.  MBCS builds are becoming more rare, and basically should be used only for legacy apps.